# Should a CLI wrapper specify function defaults?

Tags: python, cli, default-values, wrapper, argparse

In my code let's say I have a function which does most of the work:

```
def compute(x=3, y=5):
    ...
```

And I have a CLI wrapper program using argparse. I intend end users to use the CLI program and not the function directly, but also other developers may work on the source code. Argparse has the capability to add default arguments as command line arguments. I want to avoid duplicating specifying the defaults. Should default values be specified in the function definition, or the CLI wrapper?

Comment: Isn't clear what you are asking here.

Comment: @nadir what is not clear?

Answer (score 1):

You should either duplicate the defaults, or store them in variables that can be used in both places.

Here's why: the `compute` function needs to know what the defaults are so that it can properly configure its behavior.  The CLI wrapper needs to know what the defaults are so that it can properly configure its behavior.  Since neither one has awareness of the other, you have to confer that awareness on both mechanisms.